# access dropdown control from the master page to the content page using asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have a master page and the content pages in the master page i have the textbox and dropdown 
the value in the dropdown may vary according to the content pages

e.g for one content page the dropdown may contain

branchname,
   city,
   address

and let for other content page under same master page the dropdown may have values like

Contactnumber,
    EmailID,
...........
.........
  etc.....

so please help me to how can i bind that dropdown from my content page

thanks.

Comment: Why don't you let the ContentPages bind their controls themself? A ContentPage should not be dependent on a specific masterpage, the same applies to the reverse.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please do as follows:

I have created a property in the master page and called that on the content page as:

```
public DropDownList SearchList
{
    get { return ddlFilterText; }
}
```

and on the content page:

```
// place here the datasource through which the  dropdown is biding

Master.SearchList.DataSource = null;

Master.SearchList.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could go and look for the dropdown control from your content page like this:

var yourdropdown = Page.Master.FindControl("ID of the dropdown") as DropDownList;

But be aware of that the masterpage's load event is succeeded by the page's load event so you dont double bind it.

Answer (score 0):

If the values in the drop-down are dictated by the individual content pages, then my suggestion would be to store these in cache, or session, or some state-persistence mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest way to accomplish this is by adding a  [MasterType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xxwa0ff0.aspx) directive to each of your content pages.

```
<%@ MasterType virtualpath="~/Masters/Master1.master" %>
```

Then from your codebehind in the content pages you can reference the Master Page controls like so:

```
DropDownList myDropDownList = Master.TheDropDownList;
```

Andreas is correct in that you need to be aware of the [ASP.NET Event Life Cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx), so you actually bind the dropdown at the correct time.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty simple. You can 'find' the control from the content page.

Here's a sample where i'm binding to a DropDown control.

Master:

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlMaster" DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="Id" />
```

Content Page:

```
var ddlMaster = (DropDownList)Master.FindControl("ddlMaster");

ddlMaster.DataSource = dt;
ddlMaster.DataBind();
```

If you need to edit a textbox on the master page, you can also find that control and make changes to it from the content page.

Comment: but when i use to find the ddlmaster in contant page through this code the null value comes